# How to create multiple columns in a div

Tags: css, html, text, border

I was wondering how I would create multiple columns in a div. It's for a footer and I want a site map, links to social media etc.

I was going to use `<multicol>` but I then read that it was deprecated so it kind of put me off using it.

Basically I have an 80% wide DIV and I need three columns in it. Preferably each with a margin.

Css:

```
 div.bottom
        {
            height: 200px;
            width: 80%;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            margin-top: none;
            margin-bottom: none;
            border-top: 4px solid #00ccff;
            border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
            border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
            background-color: #575757;
        }
```

I just need the HTML now. Thank you for your time.

Comment: What HTML are you trying to style? We're not, despite appearances to the contrary, psychically inclined or capable. Give us an idea of how it should look, once styled.

Comment: I just need the columns set so I can enter text in the three columns.

Comment: So I gathered, but we're still guessing as to whether you want the columns to flow, from one to the next, or whether you're wanting independent lists in each column. Please, help *us* to help ***you***.

Comment: Hi David. I want then to be independent. But, this issue has already been resolved so please spend your time helping someone else.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Create three divs with `float: left;` (or right) and give them an exact `width`.

```
<div class="bottom">
  <div style="float: left; width: 33%;"></div>
  <div style="float: left; width: 33%;"></div>
  <div style="float: left; width: 33%;"></div>
</div>
```

See it [in action](http://jsfiddle.net/qdwtT/).

Comment: This does not work if the column div have borders. It will wrap to the next row if the row is not wide enough.  How are borders handled in sizing each column?

Comment: Brad, that is because of the standard CSS box model, which includes the padding and border in the sizing. You can adjust this behaviour using the `box-sizing` property.

Comment: In situations like mine, where the columns flow onto the subsequent content of the page, it might be useful to add an empty `<div style="clear: both;"></div>
`