# Column fill in css in a sequential order

Tags: css

[image]

My CSS:

```
    #columns {
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
    -webkit-column-fill: auto;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-gap: 10px;
    -moz-column-fill: auto;
    column-count: 3;
    column-gap: 10px;
    column-fill: auto;
}
```

My column count is 3 however the fill happens as seen in the picture how do i show 3 images at a time.

**Below is my jsfiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/swh36mLm/

Sorry it contains my complete css file.

Comment: As it is, this question is hard, if not impossible, to answer. The relevant information to determine the reason your CSS is not working as intended is not present. My first guess is that the total width of the area that you divided in columns is not big enough to fit three 'pictures' side-by-side. This assumes that pictures have a set width, and the area's inner width is less than 3 x pictureWidth + 20px (for the column gaps). It is however impossible for me to verify this, based on the incomplete data you provided. A JSFiddle or otherwise reproducible example of the problem would help.

Comment: It fits perfectly if there are more than 6 images that is not the reason

Comment: The point of my comment was mainly to state we can only guess. It would help if you'd put additional info/code/a fiddle in the question. It'll be more effective than adding a bounty, to get you an answer.

Comment: @HansRoerdinkholder Added it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use a CSS flexbox instead? If you change your `#columns` to be a flex container, then set the immediate children divs to a width of 33% (less, actually to accommodate for gaps, borders, etc. -- you can figure out the appropriate figure), you wind up with a three-column layout that you can continuously add to.

Since your CSS is almost 25,000 lines long, here is what I changed:

- Removed the @media rules from lines 23,142 thru 23,156
- Rewrote the `#columns` rule to be a flexbox (see code below)
- Added a `#columns > div` rule to set the widths of the children divs to 30% (again, the 30% is something you'll have to play with to get the biggest "one-third" column you can get)

```css
#columns {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

#columns > div {
  width: 30%;
}
```

I edited your JSFiddle with these changes and got the result seen below:

[image]

I hope it helps. If you want more info on CSS Flexboxes, check out this URL (it's helped me a lot in the past): [Visual Guide to CSS3 Flexbox Properties](https://scotch.io/tutorials/a-visual-guide-to-css3-flexbox-properties)

Comment: If i use this approach the cards in the lower won't align like a fitting grid as my images are of variable heights

Comment: If you change the `align-items` property in `#columns` to 'stretch' then the cards will all be the same height across each row.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have 3 columns for your content cards `column-count` isn't the right option. You can use `column-count` to [divide a long text into multiple columns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Columns/Using_multi-column_layouts). In your example you try to divide cards into multiple coulmns. It's possible if you set a height for the wrapper div, but I guess you might not receive the results you expected:

```
<div id="columns" style="height:350px;">...</div>
```

[image]

If you want to have a multi column layout, please [check out this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10676881/how-to-create-multiple-columns-in-a-div).

Answer (score 0):

"column-count" not divide on points you want,

for example in this code

```
<div class="c">...</div>
<div class="c">...</div>
<div class="c">...</div>
```

not consider every single div with "c" class as single item.

---

"column-count" divide on points that wants,

for example

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard
```

in this text make three partly equal part and show them in three columns.

---

for solution you most get every item

```
width: 33.33333333%;
```

and float them.

if you want complete code just comment for me.